# Child Form Not displaying when the Main form is not active

Tags: c#

On button click of an existing screen, I open a new form using Show() Method. Problem here is when the Main Form is active, the new Form is displayed without issues. If the Main form is not active (i.e, I am working on some other applications), then the Child form is not visible. In the Debug Mode - New form Visibility is showing as true and its window state is normal. Please advise me where could be the issue is. After opening the new form, I am running a Background Worker Thread to complete my task.

Comment: When you say "not visible", do you mean not visible at all (even through Alt+Tab), or do you mean it isn't in the foreground?

Comment: Yes It is not visible at all.

Comment: Can you include an [mcve]?

Comment: Using any functions of an invisible 'host' form to call other forms must use the visible calling form as owner and not the invisible 'host' form